# Tinymce shortcodes within shortcode contents

Tags: shortcode, tinymce, views

I am using `wp.mce.views.register` to create a simple view for my shortcode  in the tinymce editor,
this works fine but i am looking for a way to have "nested" shortcodes
e.g.

```
[column_3]
    [info_box]
        <p>Some info here!</p>
    [/info_box]
[/column_3]
```

and to have them rendered nicely.

This is simple enough frontend with `do_shordcode($shortcode_content);` but I havent been able to find an equivalent js/tinymce function.

Do anyone know how to do this if it is possible?

Comment: any luck on this? I've spent a week try to solve wp.mce.views.register for nested shortcode. It seems currently it's impossible due to the object generated from wp.mce.view text property didn't include the close tag for shortcode and the content itself.